# how can i load autocomplete with jquery on click event?

Tags: jquery, automation

how can i load autocomplete with jquery on click event???

Comment: do you mean the load the plugin or load the autocomplete suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#id').click(function() {
  // load autocomplete
});
```